# Testing the hypothesis of even distribution of random numbers in python

Tags: python, random, statistics

I need to generate random numbers and test hypothesis of even distribution of them using any criteria.
I generate numbers in the next way:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import collections

np.random.seed(945925321)
nums = []
for i in range(100000):
    nums.append(np.random.random())
```

Than I find the frequency of the number:

```
res = []
counter = collections.Counter(nums)
for item in counter.values():
    res.append(item)
```

And use a chi square criteria to test the hypothesis:

```
print(stats.chisquare(res))
```

I always get a p-value equal to 1. Of course I can round numbers to increase their frequences, but that probably not the right way to do it. 
Is this a right way to generate number and check the hypothesis?

Comment: If you want to use `chisquare`, then binning the results into a number of equal-width bins (say 1000) is exactly the right way to do it; with your current code, it's highly likely that all your frequencies will be exactly `1` (there are 2^53 different equally-likely outputs from np.random.random(), so you wouldn't expect repeats with under a million samples), and `chisquare` doesn't give you anything useful in that situation. Alternatively, you could look at other tests like [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test).

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes, KS test is probably more suitable at such data. Its results for big number of numbers is something I do expect (statistic around 0 and p-value about but not exactly 1). Thank you a lot!